# How do I stick this image and comments div together just with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I need to make the comments div of the same height as the image above.So they can stick together side by side. Here is the code:

```
<div class="main_image_wrapper">
    <img class="main_image" src="*dynamic generated image*" style="margin:0 auto">
    <div class="comments_div">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <!--Code for comments-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need to resort to javascript for this or can I do it in css? Also how do I place the comments right below the image, considering image could be of different widths everytime?

[image]

Comment: Do you want them to have the same width, or do you want them in the center? Because to me, it looks like, they actually are about the same width. Please be a bit more specific, what it should look like, and include a verifiable example of what you already have done. The few lines of HTML give us the result of the image below, so there has to be some CSS, that we need to help you.

Comment: We need to see full html and css.

Comment: ^^ ...e.g., a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Oh, sorry for being so confusing, I just needed the image and comment div to have the same *height* not width. so they can stick together by the side. I tried making them both inline block display, but that's not working. Comment div height can have max-height adjusted according to the image with scrollbar but they're not arranging horizontally to the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css positioning to make the image and comments div sticky. in order to do that, wrap your image and comments div by another div for example -

```
<div class="main_image_wrapper">
 <div class="sticky">
    <img class="main_image" src="*dynamic generated image*" style="margin:0 auto">
    <div class="comments_div">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <!--Code for comments-->
    </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

then style your sticky div in this way -

```
#sticky{
    position: -webkit-sticky;  // required for Safari
    position: sticky;
    top: 0; // required as well.
}
```

or you can use your element / div sticky using javascript / jQuery. please follow the link bellow how to make div

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/make-a-div-stick-to-top-when-scrolled-to/sticky using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Define common css for both image and comment section.

```css
#dog img, #comment {
width:200px;
height :200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dog">
    <img src= "https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/animals/thumbs/rights-exempt/mammals/d/domestic-dog_thumb.jpg">
<div>
<div id="comment">
  Wow what a cute dog; Courtesy of Natgeo.
</div>
```